# Error with training Faster R-CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, convolution, softmax

I'm trying to run Faster R-CNN on Ubuntu 16.04 with my computer with some peers.
But I'm stuck.
And I can't find same error like me on google.

```
Normalizing targets
done
Solving...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./tools/train_net.py", line 96, in <module>
    max_iters=args.max_iters)
  File "/home/david/Faster-RCNN_TF/tools/../lib/fast_rcnn/train.py", line 222, in train_net
    sw.train_model(sess, max_iters)
  File "/home/david/Faster-RCNN_TF/tools/../lib/fast_rcnn/train.py", line 95, in train_model
    rpn_cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(rpn_cls_score, rpn_label))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py", line 1686, in sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits
    labels, logits)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py", line 1535, in _ensure_xent_args
    "named arguments (labels=..., logits=..., ...)" % name)
ValueError: Only call `sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` with named arguments (labels=..., logits=..., ...)
```

I have no idea what this is error is about and how to solve this error.
Please help me

Comment: You should enhance your question with a mcve http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Also you can check out this link for the meaning of 'named argument' in python http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/optional_arguments.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
rpn_cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(rpn_cls_score, rpn_label))
```

try writing:

```
tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(rpn_label, rpn_cls_score))
```

if it doesn't work try:

```
tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=rpn_label, logits=rpn_cls_score))
```

Comment: where can i find this line?

Comment: in "lib/fast_rcnn/train.py"

Comment: yes thank you very much, i did the same change but on a different file